Read the function definition of pipe in polars python
The documentation of pipe in polars says :
DataFrame.pipe(
function: Callable[Concatenate[DataFrame, P], T],
*args: P.args,
**kwargs: P.kwargs,
) → T


args and kwargs go to the callable that the the function argument is taking
I need help reading the Callable[Concatenate[DataFrame, P], T], part.

Roughly, we can unpack the syntax behind Callable[Concatenate[DataFrame, P], T] as follows.

collections.abc.Callable is used to annotate callable objects (e.g. functions). The first element of the subscription syntax (Concatenate[DataFrame, P]) refers to the argument list of the callable and the second element (T) refers to its return type.
typing.Concatenate provides the means to specify the argument list of the callable in a way that allows parameter type(s) to be forwarded over to another callable. In the specific case of pl.DataFrame.pipe above, function takes as first parameter a dataframe and, moreover, some other parameters (annotated using the typing.ParamSpec object P), which are then forwarded to pl.DataFrame.pipe (notice P.args and P.kwargs in the signature).
In the second position of the subscription syntax, the placeholder T is used to specify the (unknown) return type of the function callable. It is then further used to indicate (in the signature of pipe) that pl.DataFrame.pipe will have the exact same return type T.

For a more detailed treatment of the typing intricacies of callables, see "Annotating callable objects" in the typing docs.
